# idaPro running on background issue

Tags: tmux, gnu-screen, ida, background-foreground

I am trying to run `idaPro` command line executable (`idaq`) in background mode using `tmux` or `screen`, but apparently it doesn't let me do that. Any idea's on how to run a batch process in background?

This is what I am getting:

```
TVision error: Can not load libcurses.so
    Without libcurses can work only with xterm/linux
./BATCH.sh: line 3: 30708 Aborted                 (core dumped)
```

Comment: What OS are you using? 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: it was centOS and Ubuntu

Comment: Was it 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: that was 64. sry for the incomplete answert